# Call a custom Add-In from my add-in in Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am developing an add-in for outlook. When the user right click on a email or an attachment, my add-in will be seen in the context menu as an item.

My problem is, there is a custom add-in which has been developed by another person and some functions of this add-in are common with my add-in. I do not want to write these functions again and basically I want to call this add-in from my add-in. For example I will show a window and if user click ABC button, that add-in will be called (it has also a gui).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can only work if the addin author explicitly exposes its functionality for the programmatic access. You could then retrieve the Addin object from the Application.COMAddIns collection and cast the Addin.Object property to some interface exposed by that addin. Again, that can only happen if the addin actually wants to expose its functionality.